# cp Command not working in Bash Script

Tags: bash, macos, unix, grep, cp

I need to copy the file(s) that are returned by a grep command to another folder. The grep command is:

```
grep -vxF -f firstOne.txt SecondOne.txt
```

I am trying to copy it using the command

```
cp `grep -vxF -f firstOne.txt SecondOne.txt` tem2/
```

The following command works fine when i run it on the command line. But when i run it in the script, it gives me the following error

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Can somebody please help me debug this? Thank you. I am running this on a Mac, just mentioning this if a solution adheres to a particular OS

Comment: maybe it's a "current directory" problem: inside the script, the `grep` returns empty, thus the `cp` command becomes: `cp tem2/`

Comment: You should use `find` for this. That is the tool for the purpose.

Comment: add `set -x` before the `cp` command in your script and see what's going wrong.

Comment: @pynexj, If i add the set -x option, i get ++ grep -vxF -f firstOne.txt SecondOne.txt
+ cp tem2/

Comment: @LiviuChircu Yes that is the problem, i can see that.. But why exactly is that problem occurring. I am in the right directory when I am executing the shell script

Comment: @sjsam - I take that point.. But isn't this an issue of the cp command not working.. Even if i use the find instead of grep, I think it would still throw the same error

Comment: what `grep -vxF -f firstOne.txt SecondOne.txt` it returns in your case @SadMad